# Is there a way to clone all repositories on github at once? In SVN I can to do so

Tags: git, github, git-clone

Are there a way to clone all repositories on github at once ?

For instance, I have three repositories:

```
  spring-akka-reactive

  angular7-springboot

  Angular-RestAPI-Contacts
```

Thus I want to clone them all instead one at a time, is it possible ?

Like cloning them all recursively ?

Just an hypothetical example:

```
git clone my_url_github -R *
```

For instance, in SVN I can to do so:

[How can I checkout multiple SVN repositories in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066079/how-can-i-checkout-multiple-svn-repositories-in-one-command)

The difference is that in my github account it's inside my url

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900294/clone-multiple-git-repositories-in-one-local-directory

Comment: That's not really what I want, he wants to copy them all, I want to do it recursively, is there a way ?

Comment: You can clone one repository at a time. You can do that either iteratively or in parallel, but cloning is singular.

Comment: That's the problem, and if if have 50 repositories, I need to enter one at time and copy all the url's to do so, the post you send I have to do the same, that's my question

Comment: And that's why I pointed you to a script which pulls all the repositories from GitHub, and iteratively clones all (50) of them. I don't see what your issue is.

Comment: Simple point, is there a way  to do so without coping, recursively ? like git add . after all commit all the files, Is there a way to do so like cloning all of them at once, my git_hub_url and some kind of command or script :     git clone url -R .   ?

Comment: Like a edited in the post above in SVN I can to do so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066079/how-can-i-checkout-multiple-svn-repositories-in-one-command

Comment: @Edion Cezar your example IS a script doing an iterative copy: `for REPO in ``ssh user@host 'ls /var/svn-repos'``

Comment: Yes, can I do something like that in github, I didn't find a way, do you have any answer ? In others I can do

Comment: Yes, a script to iteratively copy the repos is EXACTLY what's in my original comment! Arggg.

Comment: If I wanted to copy all the urls, for me I have no problem, it's exactly what I did, before your answer, It's obvious

Comment: A Script I already did

Comment: git clone all -R .

Comment: exists ? If you don't have the answer or think it's an inappropriate question, put a negative vote on the question :-)

Comment: Just another detail, In SVN I don't need to copy all the URL's to do a Script

Comment: I don't like to copy and paste, reusing code is one thing, another is copy and paste :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create (empty) wrapper-repo, which include all needed repo as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: That's one good way, I have a repository where I already do it, however that's not works for all of them , thank you very much :-)